# Changing category links to point to '#' instead of category

Tags: php, html, wordpress, tags, meta-tags

I can't seem to correctly adjust the below code to direct the category links to point to '#' instead of pointing to the category page. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'theme_framework_post_cat' ) ) :
function theme_framework_post_cat() {
  if ( 'post' == get_post_type() ) {
    $categories_list = get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', 'theme' ) );
    if ( $categories_list && theme_framework_categorized_blog() ) {
        printf( '<span class="cat-links">' . esc_html__( '%1$s', 'theme' ) . '</span>', $categories_list );
    }
  }
}
endif;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
$categories_list = strip_tags(get_the_category_list( esc_html__( ', ', 'theme' ) ));
```

strip_tags() is a PHP function that will remove all the tags that are returned by the get_the_category_list WP function.

Comment: This makes them not links. Are you wanting to do something else with them as links?

Comment: Having them not be links and just the name of the category is actually way better idea. Thank you so much!!!